# Autofill variations product on Shopify

Tags: shopify, autofill

I'm asking you a very "weird" question. 
So, I'm pretty new on shopify and I'm managing a website of my friend and she's having a lot of problems with the variations.

So, basically for 99% of the product she has 3 variations: x, y and z.
With these variations, shopify is gonna create all the combinations. The thing is that she has to create those products almost everyday and she needs to fill every single combination with its value (price, stock etc etc), which is a LOT (she has to fill something like 40-50 value per product)!

Is there a way to autofill all the combination with a certain input?
And also, is there a way to insert more the 99 variations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the unlimited options and combinations you need to use apps for that - Product Options By bold 
https://apps.shopify.com/product-options